# WPF DataGrid - retemplating cells causes bindings to not update

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid like so:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" CellStyle="{StaticResource EditableDataGridCellStyle}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I change the style of my DataGridCells with this code

```
<Style x:Key="EditableDataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

However, when I edit the text of the TextBox, the DataGrid displays the new value, but the underlying Person object does not update his Age. When I get rid of the "EditableDataGridCellStyle" and edit the DataGridCell manually (by double-clicking), it works like I expect.

How can I make sure that an edit of the TextBox will have the same effect as editing a DataGrid cell (i.e., updating the bindings)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind to the `Age` property and nothing else in your template for this to work as expected:

```
<Style x:Key="EditableDataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And yes, this unfortunately means that you need to define a different `Style` for each column. You probably better of using a `DataGridTemplateColumn`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. I would really like to be able to reuse the style.

Do you know of any "hack" to be able to specify the binding from the Column? Something like <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" CellStyle="{StaticResource EditableDataGridCellStyle}" CellStyleBinding={Binding Age} />

Or maybe I can reuse the DataGridTemplateColumn?

Comment: No. The only way for you to be able to reuse the Style would be to define it programmatically and apply it dynamically somehow. But it won't be worth the effort. Why are you using a custom template in this case anyway?

Comment: Ok, thanks. My goal with the custom template was to make the edit behavior of DataGrid more intuitive for my end-user. But I went another route and made the cell edit trigger on single-click instead of double-click.